# how do i add an index [0] to and object

Tags: xml, arrays, object

I have the following object(below):

```
object(stdClass)#49 (1) {
["NewOrder"] => object(stdClass)#50 (12) {
["BTN"] => string(10) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx"
["PreOrderTransactionId"] => string(22) "XXXXXXXX"
["PartnerOrderId"] => string(17) "XXXXXXXXXXX"
["QwestOrderId"] => string(9) "N57395699"
["SalesCode"] => string(7) "XXXXXXXX"
["OrderStatus"] => string(7) "Pending"
["OrderStatusCode"] => string(4) "OPEN"
["OrderStatusSourceSystem"] => string(5) "CPLUS"
["OrderStatusMessage"] => string(0) ""
["OrderStatusDate"] => string(10) "2013-12-09"
["OrderStatusTime"] => string(8) "08:02:30"
["ProductFamily"] => array(3) {
[0] => object(stdClass)#51 (2) {
["ProductFamilyName"] => string(7) "BUNDLE+"
["ProductLines"] => object(stdClass)#52 (3) {
  ["WTN"] => string(10) "3033689919"
  ["AppointmentDate"] => string(10) "2013-12-20"
  ["Products"] => object(stdClass)#53 (5) {
    ["ProductName"] => string(36) "INTERNET 100+ MBPS & HOME PHONE PLUS"
    ["Usoc"] => string(5) "BBBVC"
    ["Quantity"] => string(1) "1"
    ["Action"] => string(1) "I"
    ["Status"] => string(4) "OPEN"
  }
}
}
}
}
}
```

How can add an index[0] after ["NewOrder"] object to look like this:

```
object(stdClass)#49 (1) {
["NewOrder"] => array(1) {
[0] => object(stdClass)#50 (12) {
```

the reason i need to do this is because sometimes the it will only have one Order sometime it will have  multiples.If the there is only one it will fail in the for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_array($this->view->Orders->NewOrder)) {
            $this->view->Orders->NewOrder = array($this->view->Orders->NewOrder);
    Zend_Debug::dump($this->view->Orders->NewOrder);
        }
```